# Establecer tarea recurrente para un año en especifico en Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, cronjobs

Estoy utilizando el paquete `Hangfire` en una aplicación ASP.NET Core MVC para realizar tareas en segundo plano, y una de las formas de definirlas es creando tareas recurrentes.

El problema es que necesito que las tareas recurrentes se ejecuten en un año especifico o un rango de años. Esto lo puedo definir con una expresión CRON como esta `0 0 0 1 1-4 ? 2021-2022` (se ejecuta el primer dia del mes en los meses de enero a abril entre los años 2021 y 2022 a las cero horas del dia).

Un codigo de ejemplo usando Hangfire seria:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("jobId",() => Console.WriteLine("Tarea recurrente con exito."), "0 0 0 1 1-4 ? 2021-2022");
```

Pero esto me retorna una excepción cuando llamo la vista o endpoint del controlador:
[image: CronFormatException]

La excepción es clara, me indica que solo debo usar 5 o 6 digitos para la expresión CRON de la tarea recurrente de `Hangfire` y esto se debe a que usa `NCrontab` para las expresiones CRON: [NCrontab: Crontab for .NET](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab)

Tambien he visto que se pueden ejecutar filtros para el método de trabajo como en: [Trabajos recurrentes entre fechas](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/recurring-jobs-between-dates/2713/4)

Que si bien no he probado esa implementación, ocurre que los trabajos que quiero ejecutar aunque sea el mismo metodo de trabajo, tendran fechas diferentes.

Tampoco quiero crear un trabajo en segundo plano que este haciendo esta verificación ya que puede generar cierta inconsistencia en la ejecución de los mismos.

¿Existe alguna solución establecida o tengo que seguir uno de los enfoques mencionados?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en tu escenario:

1. Los CRON JOBS no tienen especificación para años. Son tareas repetitivas que se manejan por segundo, por minuto, por hora, por día de la semana, día del mes y por determinación de algún mes en particular.

- Por esto mencionado, tendrás errores si determinas un año, la expresión se rompe.

2. Esta expresión: `0 0 1 1-4 *` genera: “At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 in every month from January through April.”, dicho en el buen español, este CRON JOB se ejecutará a las 00:00, cada 1 de cada mes de Enero a Abril.

- Referencia: https://crontab.guru/#0_0_1_1-4_*

3. Ahora bien, `NCRONJOB`, se va a romper por la expresión, hay que modificarla a `0 0 0 1 1-4 *`

   ```
    /**
     * En la siguiente línea, está la explicación de cada asterisco de un grupo de 6:
    * * * * * *
    - - - - - -
    | | | | | |
    | | | | | +--- day of week(0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
    | | | | +----- month(1 - 12)
    | | | +------- day of month(1 - 31)
    | | +--------- hour(0 - 23)
    | +----------- min(0 - 59)
    +------------- sec(0 - 59)
   ```
4. Vas a tener que ajustar la lógica de verificación en el momento que se va a ejecutar y preguntar si es el año 2021 o 2022 para proceder, de lo contrario, ignorarlo. Es más, si ya pasó el año 2022, debería detenerse ese servicio.
5. Esto que dices, NO lo entiendo, van como 3 veces que leo tu pregunta y no le encuentro sentido: `Tampoco quiero crear un trabajo en segundo plano que este haciendo esta verificación ya que puede generar cierta inconsistencia en la ejecución de los mismos.` Aquí hay 2 cosas: 1. Prácticamente los CRON JOBS se ejecutan en segundo plano. 2. ¿A qué inconsistencia te refieres? En tu pregunta, no se encuentra algo relacionado.

Comment: Para el punto 1, 2 y 3 muchas gracias por explicarlo, tambien lo revise en la investigacion, solo se me hace extraño que librerias como Quartz.NET si tenga una definición para los años, aunque Hangfire es mucho mas antigua. El punto 5 me referia a inconsistencia del tipo "Genero un reporte o envio correos" de los cuales se supone ya no deberian ser enviados o actualizados, ya que el usuario puede seleccionar las fechas en que quiere programar sus tareas recurrentes, por eso necesitaba lo de los años y ocurre ese problema.

Comment: por otra parte, el punto cuatro me ilumino el foco, esa es la solución, ya que si tengo en la BD los rangos de fechas que el usuario quiere que ocurran, el trabajo en segundo plano obtiene esos detalles y solo comparo el rango final con la fecha actual, asi lo ejecuto, o elimino el cron job de Hangfire si ya paso. Muchas gracias por las aclaraciones, creo que de momento eso es lo que necesito y puedo hacer

Comment: Vale, si la respuesta te fue utilidad, hay un check para marcarla como aceptada :D Por otro lado, `solo se me hace extraño que librerias como Quartz.NET si tenga una definición para los años` ¿Extraño? Bro, lo único adicional que hacen es establecer algún IF Statement con DateTime Now Year == AñoQueDeseas y ya~. `El punto 5 me referia a inconsistencia del tipo "Genero un reporte o envio correos" de los cuales se supone ya no deberian ser enviados o actualizados` Pues, aquí tienes un problema de enfoque, tranquilamente podrías incluir un par de campos en alguna tabla para llevar el histórico.

Comment: Ese par de campos: 1. FueEnviado (bool) Sí/No True/False. 2. EnviadoEn (DateTime). Y en tu lógica, agregas la exclusión de "Datos que fueron procesados" Y aquí revisas que FueEnviado == False && EnviadoEn == null.

Comment: Entendido, aplicare estos flags para verificar el envio, mas la verificación de la fecha para decidir si ejecutar el job o no (eliminarlo), eso es todo. Me estaba enfrascando en ¿Cómo lo hacen las otras librerias? Y no en lo que realmente puede resolverlo y estaba ahi :D tan claro que no lo veia hasta que lo hiciste ver. Supongo no siempre tiene que ser todo tan complicado. De nuevo muchas gracias y te aseguro tendre en cuenta todos los consejos, me has salvado el día jaja

Comment: El desarrollo de software es un arte, es el arte de poder complicarse la vida un momento y que sea solo lo necesario para tener un punto de partida definido y poder fluir con todo lo que hay hacia la posible solución del problema :D Me alegra mucho que hayas avanzado, sigue así, vas por buen camino :D

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente, sabias palabras, por mas personas asi :D, sin mas que decir, exitos y a seguir disfrutando de este maravilloso mundo.

Comment: Un placer colaborar, muchas gracias a ti también, éxitos y a darle con todo el power 2.0!!!! :D